# Image gallery displaying images too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div( gallery div) which is FadedIn on button click and FadedOut on close button inside that div.And i want to have 2 buttons for next image and previous image the gallery has around 50 images but they seem to display slowly on chrome and on FireFox and IE even too slowly here is my code.The Div name is "FadeIn" the closing button name is "close" and the image panel inside that div where the photos are displayed is "Dimage".It is working but everytime i click next or previous it seems that i ask the server for the location of the image that should be displayed.I'm thinking of script that on pageload loads all the images and then on next/previous just gets these loaded images src but how to implement that , also i think for that i can have better solution using only HTML and CSS3
a link to the web app >> Галерия for the gallery
hotelmontecristobg.com

Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

            $('body').on('click', '#close', function () {
                $('#FadeIn').fadeOut(1000);
            });

            var indix = 1;

            var DefaultImages = new Array('MainImages/1.jpg', 'MainImages/2.jpg', 'MainImages/3.jpg',
                'MainImages/4.jpg', 'MainImages/5.jpg', 'MainImages/6.jpg',
                'MainImages/7.jpg', 'MainImages/8.jpg', 'MainImages/9.jpg',
                 'MainImages/12.jpg',
                'MainImages/13.jpg', 'MainImages/14.jpg', 'MainImages/15.jpg',
                'MainImages/16.jpg', 'MainImages/18.jpg',
                'MainImages/19.jpg', 'MainImages/20.jpg', 'MainImages/21.jpg',
                'MainImages/22.jpg', 'MainImages/23.jpg', 'MainImages/24.jpg',
                'MainImages/a1.jpg', 'MainImages/a2.jpg', 'MainImages/a3.jpg',
                'MainImages/a4.jpg', 'MainImages/a5.jpg', 'MainImages/a6.jpg',
                'MainImages/a7.jpg', 'MainImages/a8.jpg', 'MainImages/a9.jpg',
                'MainImages/b1.jpg', 'MainImages/b2.jpg', 'MainImages/b3.jpg',
                'MainImages/b4.jpg', 'MainImages/b5.jpg', 'MainImages/b6.jpg',
                'MainImages/b7.jpg',  'MainImages/b9.jpg',
                'MainImages/b10.jpg', 'MainImages/b11.jpg'
                );

            $('body').on('click', '#Hbutton1', function (event) {
                $('#FadeIn').fadeIn(1000);
                $('#Dimage').attr("src", DefaultImages[1]);
            });
            $('body').on('click', '#rightBut', function (event) {

                if (indix == DefaultImages.length - 1) {
                    indix = 0;
                }
                else {
                    indix++;
                }
                $('#Dimage').fadeOut(2000, function () {
                    $('#Dimage').attr("src", DefaultImages[indix]);
                });
                $('#Dimage').fadeIn(2000);


            });
            $('body').on('click', '#leftBut', function (event) {
                if (indix == 0) {
                    indix = DefaultImages.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                    indix--;
                }
                $('#Dimage').attr("src", DefaultImages[indix]);

            });

        });
```

Comment: Please make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can see your problem more clearly.

Comment: he tells us where the live site is so a fiddle isn't really necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your script is now all the images should be loaded when the page is loaded, javascript is client side so it won't be going to your server.

Your images are massive, I would optimize them and that should help, I would also cut that slide show down.  Most users are not going to go through 50 images find unique examples of what you want to show and cut it down around 20-25 images the combination of those two things should help speed up your load times.

You can use a site like [this](http://jpeg-optimizer.com/) to optimize your jpegs.

EDIT:
You are correct, after looking at it closer you are resetting the src attribute on each click.  I would load all the images into HTML elements and create a slideshow using CSS and Javascript/JQuery.

Here is an example of how to do so:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

No matter what solution you go with, it is always wise to optimize you images though.

Comment: but these array contains only strings and these strings are the path to the source(image) you sure that everytime you next/previous it does not communicate with the server?